# Why measured time of running NEON inline assembly code doesn't match with expected time based on number of clock cycles and core frequency?

Tags: assembly, arm, cpu-architecture, neon, cpu-cycles

```
  image width  = 4000
  image height = 2000
  number of iterations = width * height / 64 = 125 000  

  asm volatile(
  "1:                                                    \n\t"
  "prfm     pldl1keep, [%[src], #128]                    \n\t"

  "LD4   {v0.16B, v1.16B, v2.16B,v3.16B},  [%[src]], #64 \n\t" //5 cycles

  "MOVI v10.16B, #12                                     \n\t" //1 cycle

  "AND v4.16B, v0.16B, v10.16B                           \n\t" //1 cycle
  "AND v5.16B, v1.16B, v10.16B                           \n\t" //1 cycle
  "AND v6.16B, v2.16B, v10.16B                           \n\t" //1 cycle
  "AND v7.16B, v3.16B, v10.16B                           \n\t" //1 cycle

  "MOVI v11.16B, #20                                     \n\t" //1 cycle

  "SUB v8.16B, v4.16B, v11.16B                           \n\t" //1 cycle
  "SUB v9.16B, v5.16B, v11.16B                           \n\t" //1 cycle
  "SUB v10.16B, v6.16B, v11.16B                          \n\t" //1 cycle
  "SUB v11.16B, v7.16B, v11.16B                          \n\t" //1 cycle

  "ST4   {v8.16B, v9.16B, v10.16B,v11.16B}, [%[dst]], #64 \n\t" //5 cycles

  "subs  %[simd_it], %[simd_it], #1                      \n\t" //1 cycle
  "bne   1b                                              \n\t" //4 cycles
```

approximately 25 clock cycles per iteration
  125 000 * 25 = 3 125 000 cycles per image

I implemented example code in ARM NEON inline assembly (code doesn’t make sense).
There are (approximately, I used info from ARMv7 and this is ARMv8, but I don’t expect that number will be much higher) 3,1M clock cycles per whole image.

I am running on processor with frequency 1Ghz. If processor does 1G clock cycles per second, it should do 3,1M cycles in less then 4ms. But time I measured is about 14ms.

**Why it doesn’t match?** There are no other processes running on the same core.

There are conditional branches, for each iteration (bne), they will cause that pipeline needs to be refilled. **If conditional skip will be removed** and instead of it, there will be written thousand lines long code, **will it be 3-4 times faster?** Thanks

Comment: instruction execution time is not deterministic in the way that you think definitely not one per clock or anything like that.  then what are you running on (bare-metal without an operating system), what kind of memory are you using, is there a cache, is it enabled, instruction and data?  all of these things plus others on top of it being pipelined will make the execution time vary, sometimes it is just from one compile to the next depending on the other factors and if the code (or any code above it not related) changes.

Comment: how are you doing the time measurement, very often that is the problem not the code, but usually it is a combination of both.

Comment: Do not post pictures of code please.  Will retract my downvote once you replace your picture with text.

Comment: @fuz: The OP fixed their question.  Although still not much detail on how they tested, like what microarchitecture (superscalar?  out-of-order?) or cache hotness.

Answer (score 1):

- There is no reason for using `ld4` and `st4` for this algorithm.
- You should initialize `v10` and `v11` outside of the loop.
- You shouldn't put `subs` back-to-back with `b.ne`.
- You should avoid using `v8` to `v15` since they have to be preserved according to `aapcs`.
- The branch predictor will make the conditional branch consume 0 cycle.

---

```
    movi    v4.16b, #12
    movi    v5.16b, #20

.balign 64
1:
    ld1     {v0.16b-v3.16b}, [src], #64
    subs    simd_it, simd_it, #1

    and     v0.16b, v0.16b, v4.16b
    and     v1.16b, v1.16b, v4.16b
    and     v2.16b, v2.16b, v4.16b
    and     v3.16b, v3.16b, v4.16b

    sub     v0.16b, v0.16b, v5.16b
    sub     v1.16b, v1.16b, v5.16b
    sub     v2.16b, v2.16b, v5.16b
    sub     v3.16b, v3.16b, v5.16b

    st1     {v0.16b-v3.16b}, [dst], #64
    b.gt    1b
```

---

The code above consumes 16 cycles per iteration, theoretically

125,000 * 16 = 2,000,000 = 2ms @ 1Ghz

I suppose the time you are measuring will be around 12ms though since I have the feeling that you either didn't enable the cache or you are reading/writing in non-cached area.

Around 80 cycles loss per iteration looks damn plausible for cache-miss penalty of four registers.

Comment: Thank you. Is there a reason why you didn't use prfm(pldl1keep) instruction in your example? I can see significant influence when used.

Comment: @Roman To my knowledge the instruction is irrelevant, if automatic cache preload is enabled.